# Why use a hashing algorithm other than blake2_256 in a StorageMap when using decl_storage

Tags: hash, rust, substrate

It says [`decl_storage!`](https://crates.parity.io/srml_support_procedural/macro.decl_storage.html) is a "procedural macro" used for storing data to make it available in subsequent blocks.

It says that if the user is able to set the key pair, then we cannot trust the key pair, and so we must use a cryptographic hasher such as blake2_256 to prevent "other values in storage being compromised".

Why would you use a hashing algorithm (`$hash`) other than the default `blake2_256` in a [`StorageMap`](https://crates.parity.io/srml_support/storage/trait.StorageMap.html) (i.e. why would anyone use [`twox`](https://crates.parity.io/srml_support/trait.Hashable.html) instead of the default `blake2_256`)?

Also, why does it say that its just to prevent "other values in storage being compromised"? Isn't `blake2_256` also used to prevent the key pair itself from being compromised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `blake2_256` hasher is an opaque cryptographic hasher which incurs two costs/has two disadvantages:

- computationally expensive
- does not allow iterating through storage

Thus there are alternative hashers that improve on these for situations where you care about them:

- The `twox` hasher is cheap to compute, so you can use it if the blockchain controls the input to the `StorageMap`, e.g. when using a counter to index into it.
- The `blake2_128_concat` hasher concatenates the input to the hasher onto the end of the hash to allow iterating over the keys (and values) of the map.

Find more information in the updated [documentation for `decl_storage`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/macro.decl_storage.html)